# Foreach form in array validation

Tags: php, arrays, forms

Thanks for reading :D

I'm creating a online order system. You will see 3 inputs. `Partnumber`, `Quantity` and `Price`. You will only fill in Partnumber and Quantity. Price will be checked trough my database for the right price. I tried to create that function, still not working. But anyway. I included a jQuery function so you can add extra lines into the form when you want to order more products.

A little snippet so you know what i am meaning.

```
    $('#addpart').click(function(){
  var loop = $('#loop').val();
  var html;
  html = '<p>';
  html += '<input type="text" name="part[]" style="margin-left:20px;" class="text medium" id="part" placeholder="SP partnumber" />';
  html += '<input type="text" name="qty[]" style="margin-left:20px;" class="text small" placeholder="Qty" />';
  html += '<input type="text" style="margin-left:20px;" class="text small" id="price" placeholder="Price" tabindex="-1" readonly />';
  html += '</p>';
  for (i = 0; i < loop; i++) {
    $("#form").append(html);
}

});
```

So when your post this form we dont know how many fields it will be. Sometimes it will be 5 order lines, sometimes 10. 
So i start using `[]` in my input field.
The input `name` attribute will be like this: `"part[]"`.

The form will be validated with the class `Validation`.
To show my class this page will be very long ghehe.
Here is a little snippet how to use this class/function so you know the structure.

```
if(toxInput::exists()){
    if(toxtoken::check(toxInput::get('token'))){

        $toxValidate = new toxValidate();
        $toxValidation = $toxValidate->check($_POST, array(
            'name'  => array(
                'required'  => true,
                'min'               => 2,
                'max'       => 50
            )
        ));

        if($toxValidation->passed()){
    etcetcetc..
```

So with the order form it should be something like this:

```
$toxValidate = new toxValidate();
    $toxValidation = $toxValidate->check('$_POST', array(
        'part1' => array('required' => TRUE, 'maxlength' => 14),
        'part2' => array('required' => TRUE, 'maxlength' => 14),
        'part3' => array('required' => TRUE, 'maxlength' => 14),
        'part4' => array('required' => TRUE, 'maxlength' => 14),
        'part5' => array('required' => TRUE, 'maxlength' => 14)
    ));
```

How can i print this line `'part1'  => array('required' => TRUE, 'maxlength' => 14)` for every filled in line. I tried serveral ways with `foreach` and `[]`.
All didnt work.. :(

Comment: Post a link to the class `Validation` documentation.

Comment: Here we go: https://paste.ofcode.org/37W7WePcu57a8mf6QLk6vDX

But it just needs to create the array for in the `Validation->check` function. from the submitted forms. The Check needs to check each `input`. `part[0]`, `part[1]` etc

Comment: When you submit a form with an array input e.g. `part[]`, then `$_POST['part']` will be an array. Notice I said `$_POST['part']` not  `$_POST['part[]']`. Your class is limited to nonarray inputs as it is looking for the latter. You need to add logic to deal with array inputs.

Comment: Thanks, but is it not possible to convert foreach `part[]` to `part' => TRUE,`  so it will be checked by my `validation`  class? My `validation` class will check the `items` allready in a array. I need to combine the `part` array with the `forms` array which im using in the `check` function.

Comment: Or should it better to bypass the `validation` class and check it on a other way so it will be easier ?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you need to extend your `Validation` class to be able to validate arrays in the most comfortable way.

You can try to handle array variables like this (just an example):

```
$toxValidate->check($_POST, [
    'name' => [
        'required' => TRUE,
        'min' => 2,
        'max' => 50,
    ],
    'qty' => [
        'required' => TRUE,
        'array' => TRUE,
        'min' => 2,
        'max' => 14,
    ],
]);
```

Under the hood of your `Validation` class, just loop through the values of the passed `qty` array if `is_array($toxValue)` and apply your rules to every member of that array (min, max, etc.).

Also, I suggest to refactor your `Validation` class: use callbacks or class member functions to call separate validation rules (not the best OOP-way, but feasible for easy cases). Like this:

```
class Validation
{
    ...

    public function ruleMax($value)
    {
        ... // Validate value max
    }

    public function ruleMin($value)
    {
        ... // Validate value min
    }
}
```

With this approach you won't need to fully rewrite your `check` function if you need to add more validation rules to your class (or subclass).

By the way, I suggest to see how it's made in popular frameworks like Laravel:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#validating-arrays

And the class itself as an easy example (not the best of course) of rules decoupling: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Still not really getting it of your structure you suggest, but i will try something out. Arrays are not my strongest skills.
About my `Validation` class to use validation rules in function, that part i dont really get. I dont need now to rewrite my validations rules? When i need a new rule i just add a new `switch` `case`.

About Laravel. I tried to look up months ago but still dont get the structure. I learn PHP alot of the old time. The oldscool PHP and now i try to use OOP/PDO but sometimes still very hard like now.

Comment: I think i will bypass anyway this `validation` class for this part of the system because of the `multiple unknow forms`. Especially they are actually they dont need really validation rules.

Comment: > The oldscool PHP and now i try to use OOP/PDO but sometimes still very hard like now
  
That's makes sense now.

Try to look at this function: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php#L306
The code is well-commented. Find foreach loop - you will see `$this->validate()` call.

Next look at `$this->validate($attribute, $rule)` - it uses `$method = "validate{$rule}";` as a function name.

Example call: `$this->validate('name', 'min')` will lead to `$this->validateMin()` call.

This construction will help you to get rid of `switch/case`.

Comment: Now about array validation:

After the form request, you will get an array in your `$_POST['qty']`. Like this: `$arr = $_POST['qty']`.

Next you need to check if the variable is a real array, like that: `is_array($arr)`.
If you've got an array (function returned `true`), you can do `foreach` loop by all elements of this array in your `Validator`, like this: http://pastebin.com/1D56X0he

That was a pseudo-code. Also, if you want to refresh your knowledge about arrays in PHP, try to use official docs: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: So what you mean is that i need to modife my `validation` class. So instead of applying the rules like `'part' => array('required' => TRUE)`, i can apply it like this: `$Validate->('required', toxInput::get('po'));
Is that what you mean?

Comment: Not really. I've had two suggestions: 1. Extend your `Validation` class to be  able to handle array values;
2. Refactor your `Validation` class to get rid of `switch/case` statements, because it's hard to maintain and extend in the future.